# Superscripting a variable over another when building tables in R and knitr

Tags: r, knitr, superscript

I am trying to build a table, and one of my variables should have another variable superscriptet after it. I can find several related answers here on SO, but they all involve fixed values that need to be superscriptet, instead of vectors as in my case.
Also most examples involve plot legends and not tables like in my case (Although I don't think that makes much of a difference).

Example data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)

df <- crossing(
  X = seq(1:2),
  Y = c("A", "B"))

df

# A tibble: 4 x 2
      X Y    
  <int> <chr>
1     1 A    
2     1 B    
3     2 A    
4     2 B
```

I would like to mutate a new variable that is just X with Y values superscriptet after it.

Here is what I have tried (Doesn't work):

```
df %>% mutate(
  New = paste0(X, "^Y")) %>% 
  kable()

df %>% mutate(
  New = paste0(X, ^{Y})) %>% 
  kable()

df %>% mutate(
  New = paste0(X, bquote(^~{.Y}~))) %>% 
  kable()
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is `df %>% mutate(New=paste0(X, "^", Y))` what you're after?

Comment: Thank you.  I am away from my computer until this evening.  I will check first thing when I get back.  It looks like a simple effective solution.

Comment: Checked it - the script is not superscripted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tableHTML`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  X = seq(1:2),
  Y = c("A", "B"))


library(dplyr)
library(tableHTML)
```

You can slightly modify `X` with the `HTML` tag `<sup>` to display `Y` as a superset:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(X = paste0(X, "<sup>", Y, "</sup>")) %>% 
  select(X) %>% 
  tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
            escape = FALSE,
            widths = 50)
```

[image: result]

**Edit**

As pointed out by Steen, this also works with `knitr`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(X = paste0(X, "<sup>", Y, "</sup>")) %>% 
  select(X) %>% 
  knitr::kable(escape = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you. That code actually works with knitr::kable(escape = FALSE) as well. Would you like to update your answer to include that?

Comment: Of course, thank you for pointing it out. As suggested, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is it for a `pdf` output?
Because in this case the following could work:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)

df <- crossing(
    X = seq(1:2),
    Y = c("A", "B"))

df %>% mutate(
    New = paste0(X, "\\textsuperscript{", Y, "}")) %>% 
    kable(escape = FALSE)
```

Using `escape = FALSE` to add LaTeX inside the table.